# call one simple modal while another is still open

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm using simple-modal

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I have one modal that opens on a button click, is it possible to have a button within the modal that it opens trigger a second modal?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh browser modal dialogs, how I hate thee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you can't register clicks to HTML that doesn't exist yet, which it might not in this case. That's what that 'onShow' option is for. If you register events after the modal has shown itself, it should work. You might also want to unbind the new button before binding in case the modal caches that button in HTML (which would result in rebinding and refiring the function multiple times).

or you could just do delegation on the curtain. see JQuery.delegate (they may have updated that recently depending on what version of JQ you're using)

I hope you're not wanting two at the same time. It's probably not set up for that. It would be easy enough to hack but from a UI perspective, ew in most scenarios.

Comment: can you show me what the code would look like for two at the same time. i'm in over my head a bit.. thanks!